# How to make a sort of GUI in Python that has a list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, format

So, I want to make a Blackjack game but I thought I'd like to have a nice looking system where I can sort my players with a nice GUI kind of thing. I made a simple prototype in word where I want it to look like this:

```
===========================================================
-                     Player Summary                      -
===========================================================
-                                     P W L D Chips Score -
-----------------------------------------------------------
- Bruce Wayne                         5 5 0 0  100    15  -
-----------------------------------------------------------
- Timmy Jones                         6 2 0 0  150    20  -
-----------------------------------------------------------
more characters following same layout
```

I want to be able to add more characters to the game and be able to sort this list by the different categories such as points (P), wins (W), losses (L) draw (D) etc. So the list can't be hard coded for that reason.

I have the game processing through a .txt file with all my characters and their default values and as I said, the list needs to be able to read from that file and update when I use my "add" & "remove" function and "list" function.

Comment: If you want the real GUI, you could try [Dear PyGUI](https://github.com/hoffstadt/DearPyGui) or [PySimpleGUI](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The former definitely has tools for working with tables.

Comment: I don't want it to be a proper gui, I just didn't know how to explain it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.